# Problems with requirejs in a Django project

Tags: javascript, requirejs

this is my first time using requirejs, in a chess website project, and I'm encountering some errors. Here is my scripts directory structure:

```
js
│   require.js
│
├───chessboard
│       chessboard-0.3.0.js
│       chessboard-0.3.0.min.js
│
└───game_page
        board_init.js
        board_state_update_utils.js
        btn_functions.js
        game_state_ajax.js
        game_state_init.js
        on_action_update_functions.js
        require_config.js
        template_vars.js
```

My requirejs html script tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="static/js/game_page/require_config.js" src="static/js/require.js"></script>
```

My data-main file:

require_config.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        template_vars: 'template_vars',
        board_init: 'board_init',
        game_state_init: 'game_state_init',
        game_state_ajax: 'game_state_ajax',
        btn_functions: 'btn_functions',
        on_action_update: 'on_action_update_functions',
        board_state_update_utils: 'board_state_update_utils',
        chessboard: '../chessboard/chessboard-0.3.0.min'
    }
});

require(["template_vars", "game_state_ajax", "board_state_update_utils", "btn_functions",
        "game_state_init", "board_init", "on_action_update", "chessboard"],
    function (template_vars, ajax, utils, btn) {
        //code
    });
```

All the files listed in the paths object are requirejs modules that depend on each other to varying degrees, wrapped in define() calls. And the modules that are giving me problems:

game_state_init.js

```
define(["template_vars"],
    function (template_vars) {
        var game = template_vars.long_fen;
        //other code
    });
```

on_action_update_functions.js

```
define(["template_vars", "board_init", "game_state_init", "game_state_ajax", "board_state_update_utils"],
    function (template_vars, board, game, ajax, utils) {
       //code
    });
```

In the first module, I get the error game_state_init.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'long_fen' of undefined. In the second module, I get the error require.js:5 Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: on_action_update_functions. I'm not getting errors in any of the other modules, even those that are dependent on the template_vars module-- I don't know how requirejs works, but I imagine I would see errors in those files as well if there was a problem. What could be going on here? Please let me know if you need additional information to understand the problem.

Comment: What is in `template_vars.js`? (Tangential note: quite a few of your key-value pairs in `paths` have a value identical to the key. You can remove such pairs as they are redundantly telling RequireJS to do exactly the same thing it would do by default.)